# how to rank over partition in MySql

Tags: mysql, window-functions

Im new use MySql database, I face the problem that I can solve it if in SQL server Database, but I cant do it in mysql this bellow my case

MyTable:

```
Name    Price
abs     100
abs     200
abs     60
trx     19
trx     20
abs     10
qwe     25
qwe     50
qwe     10
qwe     10
```

Result Expected:

```
Name    Price   Rank
abs      200    4
abs      100    3
abs      60     2
abs      10     1
qwe      50     4
qwe      25     3
qwe      10     2
qwe      10     1
trx      20     2
trx      19     1
```

could anyone help me how to make query like index result pict
with Mysql

Comment: Try googling mysql rank and pick a suitable answer.

Answer (score 6):

Using variable you can find `Rank`. 
Like this:

```
SELECT Name, Price, Rank
FROM (
      SELECT Name,
             Price,
             CASE WHEN @name = Name
                     THEN @id:=@id+1
                  ELSE @id:=1
             END AS Rank,
             @name:= Name AS dummy
      FROM myTable, (SELECT @name:=NULL, @id:=0) AS t
      ORDER BY Name,Price
     ) AS x
ORDER BY Name, Price DESC, Rank DESC
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Name    Price   Rank
---------------------
abs      200    4
abs      100    3
abs      60     2
abs      10     1
qwe      50     4
qwe      25     3
qwe      10     2
qwe      10     1
trx      20     2
trx      19     1
```

Link to the Demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a98575/4

Comment: Too bad MySQL doesn't support variables in a view. I could switch to a rank() function, but that isn't available until MySQL 8. (I have MySQL 5)