# How to use sum over partition (withhout window function) in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, mysql-5.7

I want to know how mysql 5.7 engine works the same as sum over part.
Cannot replace query engine because it is not a personal operation.

There was an attempt to resolve it through the @set variable function, but I find it difficult to get a cumulative sum for each of the four columns.

I looked at the link below, but it was a little bit difficult to resolve.
[how to rank over partition in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040359/how-to-rank-over-partition-in-mysql)

My table

```
id      a      b     c     d
----------------------------
abs     1      0     0     1
abs     0      1     1     0
abs     1      0     1     0
abs     1      1     1     1
qwe     0      0     0     0
qwe     0      0     0     1
qwe     1      0     1     0
qwe     1      1     0     1
trx     0      1     1     0
trx     1      1     0     0
```

Expected

```
id      a      b     c     d
----------------------------
abs     1      0     0     1
abs     1      1     1     1
abs     2      1     2     1
abs     3      2     3     2
qwe     0      0     0     0
qwe     0      0     0     1
qwe     1      0     1     1
qwe     2      1     1     2
trx     0      1     1     0
trx     1      2     1     0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for correcting the questions in the right way. @Barbaros Özhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want cumulative sums for each column.  In order for this to work, you need a column that specifies the ordering -- SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Assuming you have such a column, then the following would often work:

```
select t.*,
       (@a := if(@id = id, @a + a, 0)) as a,
       (@b := if(@id = id, @b + b, 0)) as b,
       (@c := if(@id = id, @c + c, 0)) as c,
       (@d := if(@id = id, @d + d, 0)) as d,
       @id := id
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by t.id, ?  -- column for the ordering
     ) t cross join
     (select @id := -1, @a := 0, @b := 0, @c := 0 @d := 0) params;
```

However, this is not *guaranteed* to work, because MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`.  So, I think subqueries might be the simplest method:

```
select t.id,
       (select sum(t2.a) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.? <= t.?) as a,
       (select sum(t2.b) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.? <= t.?) as b,
       (select sum(t2.c) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.? <= t.?) as c,
       (select sum(t2.d) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.? <= t.?) as d
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks ! 
I'll try it  
I have a column for ordering - timestamp

Comment: Hi Gordon,
I try it.but, it didn't work.
error messeage:  t doesn't exist 
I think t is because the table is subquery in my query.

Comment: @장수영 . . . `t` is just a placeholder for your table name, which is not mentioned in the question.